# Android: Able to return ArrayList but NOT a LiveData array list

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am unable to get a LiveData ArrayList from a Room database but I am able to retrieve a standard ArrayList and cannot figure out why.

I have run this code in debug mode and the ArrayList returns a size of 4, which it should.  The LiveData ArrayList, when get value is used returns null.  I have run the LiveData query both within an executor and outside of the executor and it returns null.

Declarations

```
public LiveData<List<CourseEntity>> courseEntities;
private List<CourseEntity> courseData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Code outside of executor

```
public void loadData(final int termId) {

        courseEntities = courseRepository.getCourseByTermId(termId);
        courseData = courseEntities.getValue();

}
```

Code inside executor

```
public void loadData(final int termId) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                courseEntities = courseRepository.getCourseByTermId(termId);
                courseData = courseEntities.getValue();

            }
        });
    }
```

Code using just an ArrayList

```
public void loadData(final int termId) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                courseData = courseRepository.getCourseByTerm(termId);
            }
        });
    }
```

Queries from Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM course " +
            "WHERE term_id = :termIdSelected ORDER BY course_start" )
    LiveData<List<CourseEntity>> getCourseByTermId(int termIdSelected);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM course WHERE term_id = :termIdSelected ORDER BY course_start")
    List<CourseEntity> getCourseByTerm(int termIdSelected);
```

This produces a null value for the LiveData instead of a value of 4 like the plain ArrayList produces.  The only difference being the LiveData wrapper for the result.  Any wisdom someone can share would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a Room `@Dao` return a `LiveData` (or an RxJava type like `Observable` or `Single`), the generated implementation will do the actual work on a background thread. So, when `getCourseByTermId()` returns, the work will not yet have begun, so the `LiveData` will not have results yet.

Reactive types, like `LiveData`, are meant to be observed. So, your activity/fragment/whatever would `observe()` the `LiveData` and react to the result when it is delivered.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense.  I am trying to observe the LiveData in a recycler view.  I am new to Android and not really clear on how to make that happen.

Comment: @MattSpriggs: Your activity or fragment that has the `RecyclerView` would observe the `LiveData`, then update the `RecyclerView` with the results. The first parameter to `observe()` on `LiveData` is a `LifecycleOwner`, so the `LiveData` knows when your activity/fragment gets destroyed and stuff. `AppCompatActivity` and the library edition of `Fragment` are each a `LifecycleOwner`, which is why they are the ones to observe the `LiveData`. The second parameter is an `Observer` (or equivalent lambda expression), where you will get your `List<CourseEntity>` and can update your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Okay, perfect!  I had it all set up, just had some observer code out of sequence.  Thank you so much for your helpful answers!